# Vue.js - Custom plugin function is undefined

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have created a simple plugin for my Vue2.js project to get some lists for my select fields in forms. The plugin should make some axios call and return the response.

```
const ListSelector = {
  install (Vue){
    Vue.mixin({

      methods: {
        getSubscriberType: function() {
          this.$http
            .get('/web/admin/contract/subscribers')
            .then(function(response) { return response.data })
        },
//other methods (they do not work the same...)...
      }
    })
  }
}

export default ListSelector
```

I registered the plugin in my main.js

```
import ListSelector from './backend/selectable'
Vue.use(ListSelector)
```

Now, if i try to call the plugin method in a component, i get that is undefined

```
<template>
...
<b-form-select v-model="form.type" :options="options" id="type" required></b-form-select>
...
</template>

<script>
export default {
data(){
  return {
    options: {}
  }
},
mounted(){
  this.options = this.getSubscriberType()
  }
}
<script>
```

I get that `this.getSubscriberType()` is undefined

EDIT: i actually see that the function is fired (i put an alert in it... but if i do a `console.log(this.getSubscriberType())` in the component, i get undefined...

Comment: what happens when you `console.log(this.getSubscriberType)` without the parenthesis

Comment: I get something like function [{native code}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your method never actually returns anything. `$http.get()` returns a promise, and promises are by their nature asyncronous.

```
const ListSelector = {
  install (Vue){
    Vue.mixin({

      methods: {
        getSubscriberType: function() {
          this.$http
            .get('/web/admin/contract/subscribers') //returns a new promise
            .then(function(response) { //Executes after the promise resolves
                return response.data //not in the same scope as getSubscriberType
            })
            // getSubscriberType completes without a return value, hence undefined
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Because the function resolves before the promise is resolved, the getSubscriberType does not even have the response available to it.

Instead, you want to return the promise.

```
        getSubscriberType: function() {
          return this.$http.get('/web/admin/contract/subscribers') // now returns promise
        }
```

Then you would do whatever you need to do with the response locally when it completes

```
var self = this // gives you a way to access local scope when the promise resolves

getSubscriberType().then(funciton(response) {
  self.subscriberType = response.data
})
```

In this example, it would set the subscriberType value on the component when the http call completes successfully.

Comment: Thanks it works in this way, even if the result is not so good as I thought because there is no much time gain in making the plugin instead of a direct call in the component to axios